# Notation vs syntax

Tags: difference

If I talk about programming language I will use a word "syntax"(and/or "grammar").

If I am looking for "smaller" things like "how to write very large numbers" I will use a word "notation" as in ["Knuth's up-arrow notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

However a programming language like the [BF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bf#Language_overview) uses 8 symbols but people still use "syntax" ([source](https://blog.klipse.tech/brainfuck/2016/12/17/brainfuck.html)).

Does it mean that I could use "syntax" for all things but I should prefer "notation" for a small things?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about a programming language, not the English language.

Comment: @Astralbee up arrow notation is not a programming language.

Comment: Ok, so it is *mathematical terminology*. It still isn't everyday English grammar. Terminology belongs to a specific discipline, it doesn't always follow the rules of English grammar. Is there a mathematical site on SE where you could ask this question of people who know Up Arrow Notation?

Comment: @Astralbee I'm not sure about "syntax" but I don't think "notation" is a math-specific concept. 
If it is not "everyday enough" for ell.se should I migrate it to english.se?

Comment: I agree "syntax" is a grammar term, also used in the programming world to denote the correct construction of code. But the answer of whether it is the correct terminology for specific situations is not one found in English grammar.

Comment: "Syntax" is almost exclusively used in computing, and not really anywhere else. "Notation" is far more standard.